# Replicate model with laravel generating incorrect sql

Tags: laravel-4

We are using laravel 4.2

I am replicating a model

```
$model = $model->replicate();
```

Then when I go to save the model, it is trying to create an sql statement based on the associative and indexed values of the array.

"0" index is there by itself as the column named after the primary key has been removed

```
Column '0' not found (SQL: insert into "obl" ("0", "1", "obl_id", "2", "obl_dscrptn", "3", "
```

We are using a custom database provider (sqlanywhere), 
so I am not sure if the problem lies with that or laravel.

The replicate function seems to be un-documented, although I have seen a number of posts referencing it's use.

Has anyone else struck this issue?

Comment: see this, I hope that might help you [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-clone-model-and-its-relationship)

Comment: @Qazi, that is unrelated, this model has no relationships. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain little more. That what actually you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years later, but the solution is to check your database.php config and make sure you set the correct fetch method:

```php
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
```